# Joomla default backend controller

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I am following the 'Developing a MVC Component' for Joomla.

While coding the frontend, the default controller in `com_helloworld\site\controller.php` was left empty as shown below

```
\\----com_helloworld\site\controller.php----

<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

/**
 * HelloWorld Component Controller
 */
class HelloWorldController extends JControllerLegacy
{

}
```

This was because, if left empty, the default behavior is to call the `display()` function of the JControllerLegacy class which would, in turn by default, call the view `com_helloworld\site\views\helloworld\view.html.php`.

Now I have reached Part 7 of the tutorial. Here we are going to start coding the administrator backend.

But now, the `com_helloworld\admin\controller.php` is not just an empty class. it as a `display()` function of its own.

```
\\---com_helloworld\admin\controller.php----

<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

/**
 * General Controller of HelloWorld component
 */
class HelloWorldController extends JControllerLegacy
{
        /**
         * display task
         *
         * @return void
         */
        function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false) 
        {
                // set default view if not set
                $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
                $input->set('view', $input->getCmd('view', 'HelloWorlds'));

                // call parent behavior
                parent::display($cachable);
        }
}
```

What would happen if we also left this class as empty? Would it call a default `helloworld` view from the `admin\views\` folder?

Also, I just saw there exists a joomla class called `JControllerAdmin`. Should I use that for my backend? The tutorial given in the Joomla documentation is for Joomla 2.5. They do not have a tutorial focussing entirely on Joomla 3.0.

Comment: Try it! If memory serves me it defaults to a view with the same name as the component (minus the `com_` part).

Comment: Yes i tried it! And it works as I expected :D